# WPF Redraw grid border after InvalidateVisual

Tags: c#, wpf

I have custom grid that extends from Grid which puts borders for each grid cell in the overriden OnRender method. Problem is my grids are dynamic so the number of columns and rows changes runtime. I have managed to change the number of RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions after detecting the number changes from the ViewModel. After the new grid rows and columns are added I force the redraw by calling InvalidateVisual and UpdateLayout on the grid which forces the overriden OnRender method to be called again. But on the screen I still see the old grid borders not the new ones. Here is the OnRender method.

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
{
    double leftOffset = 0;
    double topOffset = 0;
    Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3);
    Pen darkPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 6);
    pen.Freeze();
    darkPen.Freeze();

    foreach (RowDefinition row in this.RowDefinitions)
    {
        dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, topOffset), new Point(this.ActualWidth, topOffset));
        topOffset += row.ActualHeight;
    }
    // draw last line at the bottom
    dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, topOffset), new Point(this.ActualWidth, topOffset));

    foreach (ColumnDefinition column in this.ColumnDefinitions)
    {
        dc.DrawLine(darkPen, new Point(leftOffset, 0), new Point(leftOffset, this.ActualHeight));
        leftOffset += column.ActualWidth;
    }
    //draw last line on the right
    dc.DrawLine(darkPen, new Point(leftOffset, 0), new Point(leftOffset, this.ActualHeight));

    base.OnRender(dc);
}
```

I am new to WPF so I am not sure why the view is not updating. I'm not sure if I am doing it wrong or not. I have debugged this method and made sure I have the correct number of Row and Column definitions when this method is called after the update. Here is the picture after the grid has been updated but the borders are in old places

[image: Border in wrong place]

Comment: Can you choose a random pen color on each draw? If you get different colors after redraw then you probably need to clear the canvas.

Comment: @TyCobb, I have modifed my OnRender method to pick a random color each time. I'm seeing new colors each time but the lines are still the old. I'm not sure how to clean up the canvas. I am not using any Canvas object. I am drawing the line using drawingContext.DrawLine method. How should I erase my entire screen?

Comment: I meant canvas in a general term. Clearing is usually just drawing a rectangle to fill the entire area.

Comment: I found the problem at last. The newly added Rows and Columns had Actual Height and Width of 1 so the lines were drawn at the end of the screen for them.  :(